# My dictionary counts letter instead of words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a text string and removed all non alphabetical symbols and added whitespaces in between the words, but when I add them to a dictionary to count the frequency of the words it counts the letters instead. How do I  count the words from a dictionary?

```
dictionary = {}  

for item in text_string:
    if item in dictionary:
        dictionary[item] = dictionary[item]+1
    else:
        dictionary[item] = 1
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: How is python supposed to know what a "word" is? If you want to iterate over words, you have to split the string into words first.

Comment: Just print stuff to see what you are working on. Do not suppose it should work.

Comment: The iterator on built-in `str` yields each character one by one, explaining what you are getting. To iterate on words, use `split` like others  have mentionned in their answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
for item in text_string:
```

to this

```
for item in text_string.split():
```

---

[Function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) `.split()` splits the string to words using whitespace characters (including tabs and newlines) as delimiters.

Comment: And use counter instead pf doct it's better

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Since you state that your words are already whitespace separated, you need to use `str.split` to make a list of words.

An example is below:

```
dictionary = {}  

text_string = 'there are repeated words in this sring with many words many are repeated'

for item in text_string.split():
    if item in dictionary:
        dictionary[item] = dictionary[item]+1
    else:
        dictionary[item] = 1

print(dictionary)

{'there': 1, 'are': 2, 'repeated': 2, 'words': 2, 'in': 1,
 'this': 1, 'sring': 1, 'with': 1, 'many': 2}
```

---

Another solution is to use `collections.Counter`, available in the standard library:

```
from collections import Counter

text_string = 'there are repeated words in this sring with many words many are repeated'

c = Counter(text_string.split())

print(c)

Counter({'are': 2, 'repeated': 2, 'words': 2, 'many': 2, 'there': 1,
         'in': 1, 'this': 1, 'sring': 1, 'with': 1})
```